# How to find difference of consecutive rows for different users in sql2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I am trying to find the difference of numbers in consecutive rows, by user.

```
update [current]
set diff= 
   ISNULL([next].number, 0) - [current].number
FROM
   my_table       AS [current]
LEFT JOIN
   my_table       AS [next]
      ON [next].ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM my_table WHERE ID > [current].ID)
where [current].Date = [next].Date
and [current].User = [next].User
```

This code does not allow me to differentiate the users.
It just finds the difference of the consecutive rows, for all users.
I want it to find the difference of the consecutive rows for the same user.

Please help.

Comment: So if the rows were like Anna 1, Bob 2, Anna 3, would the diff for the first be 2 ( 3- 1) or -1 (0 -1) because the two Anna rows are not "consecutive"? As in, when you say consecutive do you mean literally consecutive, or simply the next row for that user as ordered by ID?

Comment: My code is giving me 1. (Bob 2 - Anna 1)
But I want it to give me 2. (Anna 3 - Anna 1)

Comment: Let me give you an example of what I want to achieve.

User    Number    Diff,
Anna    1         NULL,
Bob     2         NULL,
Bob     3         1,
Anna    4         3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the next number for a user, move your WHERE conditions into your ID-matching JOIN:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    my_table AS [current]
    LEFT JOIN my_table AS [next]
        ON [next].ID = (
            SELECT 
                MIN(ID) -- get first ID
            FROM
                my_table 
            WHERE
                ID > [current].ID  -- greater than the current
                and my_table.[User] = [current].[User] -- same user
                and my_table.[Date] = [current].[Date] -- same day
        )
```

Comment: The `LEAD()` and `LAG()` analytic functions in SQL Server 2012+ can be used to determine this more easily, but if you're still on SQL Server 2000 in 2014 I'm guessing you won't be upgrading any time soon.

Comment: @KyleHale It worked perfectly. Thanks!!!
This company uses SQL2000 and are planning to upgrade by mid 2015.
I'm a noob since I learnt 2008+